# WWW::Mechanize fetch frame after submit in another frame

Tags: perl

I have a webpage with 3 frames. The first frame has a form and when the form is submitted, the second frame loads some data. I need to be able to read the data in the second frame. What I have so far is this,

```
# Use WWW::Mechanize to download webpage
my $mechanize = WWW::Mechanize->new(
        noproxy  => 0,
        stack_depth => 5,
        autocheck => 1
);
$mechanize->proxy( https => undef );
my @frames;
eval{
    my $me=$mechanize->get('link');
    $me->is_success or die $me->status_line;
    @frames = $mechanize->find_link( 'tag' => 'frame' ); # three frames
    $me=$mechanize->get($frames[0]->url);
    $me->is_success or die $me->status_line;
};

my $rb_value = 2000;
my $dt = '06/30/2011'
$mechanize->set_fields(
    'idxevent' => $rb_value,
    'mindate' => $dt
);
$mechanize->submit();
```

Now I need to retrieve the content of the second frame. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with the frameset, get the url of the frame holding the form directly and submit it. Get the result of $mechanize->submit() in a variable, and then you can access it by calling the content() method:

```
$result = $mechanize->submit();
print $result->content();
```

Mechanize does not care about the frameset and the submit target, it just gets the reply from the server so the same will apply for a normal frame-less layout.

You can find an example [here](http://itworkarounds.blogspot.com/2011/07/automate-web-clicks-in-perl-with.html#get_content)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the synopsis of [WWW::Mechanize::Frames](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFrames).